# How do I get HoloViews to display in Google Colabs notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, holoviews

I can't get any HoloViews graphics to display in any [Google Colabs](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb) notebook.

For example even the simple Bokeh example right out fo the [HoloViews introduction](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html)

```
points = hv.Points(np.random.randn(500,2))
points.hist(num_bins=51, dimension=['x','y'])
```

fails to show anything, without any error being reported, while the same code (and all example code from HoloViews) works fine in local Jupyter notebooks.

If I download the Colabs notebook locally and open it, I see the following where I say nothing for output in Colabs:

> No (safe) renderer could be found for output. It has the following MIME types: application/javascript, application/vnd.bokehjs_load.v0+json

How do I get Bokeh HoloViews to display in Google Colabs notebooks?

Answer (score 11):

See https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/3551 .  Colaboratory has some serious limitations on how it handles notebooks, and for now you have to do this once:

```
import os, holoviews as hv
os.environ['HV_DOC_HTML'] = 'true'
```

Then for every single cell with a plot in it you have to re-load the JS:

```
hv.extension('bokeh')

hv.Curve([1, 2, 3])
```

It would be great if Google could fix that, as it's unworkable in my opinion.

Comment: A shorthand for setting environment is %env magic. `%env HV_DOC_HTML=true`

Comment: It's weird as holoviews works fine in Kaggle notebooks.

Comment: Kaggle notebooks are essentially just ordinary Jupyter, which is already well supported, while colab is a highly customized fork of Jupyter that diverged from the main branch quite some time ago and (mostly for security reasons) has disabled most of the machinery for JS/Python communication.  Colab is now adding new APIs to allow packages to support it, so I hope there will be progress on this front soon.